# How to move trackbar automatically

Tags: c#

Hi I'm trying to make `MP3` player with `C#` language and I'm facing a problem.

I want to make `SeekBar` with `TrackBar`. So, I want my thumb to move periodically.

But it seems like there's no proper function for me to use....

Is there anyone who knows how to do it??

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please be way more specific.

Answer (score 0):

```
double duration = double.Parse(trackBar1.Value.ToString()) / double.Parse(trackBar1.Maximum.ToString());
                axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition =axWindowsMediaPlayer1.currentMedia.duration * duration;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Rather than only post a block of code, please *explain* why this code solves the problem posed. Without an explanation, this is not an answer.